# ruby csv file encoded to utf-8 but windows excel not recognising

Tags: ruby, utf-8

In ruby i am generating CSV file while opening the file I mentioned it as UTF-8 encoding. The code is given below.In linux and mac it is working fine but in windows when i am trying to open the csv file excel  is not recognizing as UTF-8. What can i do so that windows does recognize it as UTF-8 encoding.
    `CSV.open(File.join(Rails.public_path,"/csv_uploads/#{csv_name}.csv")`, "w:UTF-8").

I even manually encode the items in the file to UTF-8.

```
`result[2].encode('UTF-8')`.
```

Comment: Does the resulting file also have a BOM - Byte Order Mark - at the beginning?  Windows apps usually works better when it's there.

Comment: yes i added and tried CSV.open(File.join(Rails.public_path,"/csv_uploads/#{csv_name}.csv"), "w:bom|UTF-8")  but no luck.

Comment: It's funny that I got the same problem since 2 or 3 days ago in my app ... even thought it worked until then.

Comment: I also tried adding a bom and even specified w:utf-8 but still windows is not recognizing it

Comment: you can refer this link https://medium.com/praaveen/rails-csv-generation-with-i18n-content-to-support-linux-ubuntu-mac-and-windows-27ecb2334cc0

Answer (score 1):

While writing itself need to be use open_mode and bom.

**Important things to note here is open mode and bom**

open_mode = "w+:UTF-16LE:UTF-8"

bom = "\xEF\xBB\xBF"

**Before writing the CSV insert BOM**

f.write bom

f.write(csv_file)

**Example I18n content**

**In Mac and Linux**

Swedish : Förnamn 
English : First name

**In Windows**

Swedish : FÃ¶rnamn
English : First name

Example code:

```
def user_information_report(report_file_path, user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    I18n.locale = user.current_lang
    open_mode = "w+:UTF-16LE:UTF-8"
    bom = "\xEF\xBB\xBF"
    body user, open_mode, bom
  end

def headers
    headers = [
        "ID", "SDN ID",
        I18n.t('sys_first_name'), I18n.t('sys_last_name'), I18n.t('sys_dob'),
        I18n.t('sys_gender'), I18n.t('sys_email'), I18n.t('sys_address'),
        I18n.t('sys_city'), I18n.t('sys_state'), I18n.t('sys_zip'),
        I18n.t('sys_phone_number')
    ]
  end

def body tenant, open_mode, bom
    File.open(report_file_path, open_mode) do |f|
      csv_file = CSV.generate(col_sep: "\t") do |csv|
        csv << headers
        tenant.patients.find_each(batch_size: 10) do |patient|
          csv <<  [
              patient.id, patient.patientid,
              patient.first_name, patient.last_name, "#{patient.dob}",
              "#{translate_gender(patient.gender)}", patient.email, "#{patient.address_1.to_s} #{patient.address_2.to_s}",
              "#{patient.city}", "#{patient.state}",  "#{patient.zip}",
              "#{patient.phone_number}"
          ]
        end
      end
      f.write bom
      f.write(csv_file)
    end
  end
```

**Windows and Mac**

File can be opened directly by double clicking.

**Linux (ubuntu)**

While opening a file ask for the separator options -> choose “TAB”